# XV-11 gmapping map_server issues

Tags: navigation, odometry, map-saver, gmapping, xv-11-laser-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Below are the commands that I have previously been attempting to use to initialize gmapping with the Neato XV-11 lidar. The laser data is published to "/scan" . The issue I have been stumped by has been "[INFO] [1330801449.815455981]: Waiting for the map" So a map is never created. /odom is not on rxgraph as it is with many other gmapping tutorials so it may have something to do with that missing node. Also "rosbag record -O mylaserdata /scan /tf" tells me that no clock is received. I would like to know how to successfully use my XV-11 Lidar with gmapping for SLAM.

---

Build a map

---

cd ros
. setup.sh

rosmake gmapping

roscore

////////////////////////////////////////////////
New Tab
////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
rosmake --rosdep-install xv_11_laser_driver
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////
Plug in USB to XV-11 Lidar
////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////
New Tab
////////////////////////////////////////////////

rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link scan 100

////////////////////////////////////////////////
New Tab
////////////////////////////////////////////////

rosparam set use_sim_time true
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan

---

Save map (New Tab)

---

rosrun map_server map_saver -f my_lab_map

(To check if data is being published:
rostopic echo --noarr -n 1 map)

---

Create own bag (New Tab)

---

rosbag record -O mylaserdata /scan /tf

(Ctrl+C to end capture)

rosbag play mylaserdata.bag

---

Watch mapping (New Tab)

---

rosmake rviz
rosrun rviz rviz /static_map:=/dynamic_map

=======================================================================================

Ok well I installed the scan_tools stack and proceeded to try the demo and I got this rxconsole error: "Node: /laser_scan_matcher_node
Time: 1282836372.076217409
Severity: Warn
Location: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-scan-tools-1.1.0/debian/ros-electric-scan-tools/opt/ros/electric/stacks/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/src/laser_scan_matcher.cpp:LaserScanMatcher::getBaseToLaserTf:620
Published Topics: /rosout, /tf, /pose2D

ScanMatcher: Could not get initial laser transform(Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/laser] to frame [/base_link])." So I changed /laser to /scan and now I receive "[ WARN] [1330810596.512410015, 1282836375.091389701]: ScanMatcher: Skipping scan
[ WARN] [1330810597.521016044, 1282836376.099091865]: ScanMatcher: Could not get initial laser transform(Frame id /laser does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /scan exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.)"

I'm new to ROS so I'm absolutely sure I'm doing something wrong and it's not the laser_scan_matcher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29021/xv-11-gmapping-map_server-issues/) by [Autrywk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1899/autrywk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-03-03**:
Make sure you publish a static tf from base_link to laser, and set the publish_tf parameter of scan_matcher to true. Also please review the wiki pages of laser_scan_matcher and scan_gmapping, everything is documented there. Laser_scan_macther has an example launch file with bag data you can examine.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-03-03**:
The topic of the laser data should be called /scan. The frame of the laser data should be called /laser.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-03-03**:
The default frame_id for the XV11 is 'neato_laser', not 'laser', so you'll have to make sure to publish the correct tf's.

**Comment by [Autrywk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1899/autrywk/) on 2012-03-03**:
When I initialize the tf as: "rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link neato_laser 100" I receive the same amount of errors. [ WARN] [1330815201.923587244, 1282836389.428243224]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /base_link at time 1.28284e+09 according to authority

**Comment by [Autrywk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1899/autrywk/) on 2012-03-03**:
/laser_scan_matcher_node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`slam_gmapping` requires a source of odometry, in the form of a tf pusblished from `odom` to `base_link`

Either of these can resolve your issue. In conjunction to `slam_gmapping`:

- Run [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf), in the case that you have an odometric sensors such as wheel encoders, and a driver for them that can publish an Odom message
- Run [laser_scan_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher) if you have no odometric sensors

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Autrywk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1899/autrywk/) on 2012-03-03**:
Thank you for such a quick response. I will run laser_scan_matcher and post my results shortly.

**Comment by [Autrywk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1899/autrywk/) on 2012-03-03**:
I've edited my initial post regarding the demo.launch